# API call not working on ios interactive widget (iOS 17 / Xcode 15 beta 8)

Tags: ios, swift, widget, xcode15

I am building by connecting an iOS 17-version device to the Xcode 15 beta 8 version.
A problem occurred while attempting an API call in the interactive widget intent.

After building the main app and building the widget extension, if I make an API request in wi-fi mode, it works fine, but after stopping all builds (simulator, widget extension) for testing and closing the app, URLSession requests are not made in cellular data mode. Is this an error that occurs because it is a beta version?